# WPF - Need to access a rectangle element in ItemsControl in code

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I'm making a simple game, a brick/block breaker game. I have the blocks drawing on the screen where I need them correctly. Yet, I want to find a way to use a user defined delegate and a custom event to detect collision between one Rectangle(the ball) to another Rectangle(a block) using Rectangle.IntersectsWith() method. I want the impacted block to report the event, so I can make it disappear.

In order to generate my blocks I use a set of WPF XAML code that creates an ItemsControl element in a Canvas(gameboard) that contains a Rectangle. In my code behind I bind the ItemsControl ItemsSource to a list of generic type Block class. This Block class is super simple, it just holds a boolean. If the block is true, the binded block will cause the ItemsControl trigger to enable the Rectangle.

The ball is a Rectangle element in WPF defined in the Canvas. So, I can provide any code necessary here, but to start off, I posted what I felt was relevant to get the idea across to start...

Any tips, suggestions, or ideas to achieve this?

C#: MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void BindBlocks()
{
    Blocks = new List<Block>();
    for (var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
    {
        for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++)
        {
            Blocks.Add(new Block(true));
        }
    }
    ItemsControl_BlockBinding.ItemsSource = Blocks;
}
```

WPF: MainWindow.xaml

```
<!--BLOCKS-->
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl_BlockBinding" Canvas.Top="16" Canvas.Left="17">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid x:Name="Grid_BlockField" Height="370" Width="730" Columns="8" ClipToBounds="True">
                <UniformGrid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" Opacity="0.8" ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="8"/>
                </UniformGrid.Effect>
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle_Block" IsEnabled="{Binding (local:Block.BlockState)}" Fill="AliceBlue" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="3,3,3,3"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="Rectangle_Block"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="Rectangle_Block"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681528/collision-detection-during-user-control-movement-for-wpf-c-sharp-in-visual-studi) will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link Pulle, but I might be too inexperienced in WPF to translate the info from that post to my project. For what I'm seeing, that post involves the Changed event of an animated Rect element. What I'm looking for is to make a collision event that is unique behavior for my Rectangle element in my ItemsControl's DataTemplate. When a Rectangle intersects 'this', fire off this event.